# Querying multiple relationships in Laravel and left join another table

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

i'm trying to do something perhaps a bit too crazy with Eloquent right now, i have a database where i have the following Tables

```
Crons - (Has Many) - Campaign - (Has Many) - Leads - (Has Many) - Conversions
```

I need to get all leads from a **Cron**, that have **no entries** in the **Conversions** table in the last *X amount of days*

I'm thinking of using a **Scope** on the **Cron** model but i'm completely stuck on how to proceed from here.

```
public function scopeWithValidLeads($query) {

    return $query->with(['leads' => function($q) {



    }]);

}
```

So i need to get LEADS where the following is true.

A - The leads belong to a campaign associated with the Cron via a Many-To-Many relationship.

B - They have no record in the *conversions* table **Under this specific campaign** or if they do, that the lead is **older** than X amount of days.

Answer (score 0):

You can get your desired result using [`doesntHave()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence) method like this:

```
$x = 10; // last 10 days
$crons = Cron::doesntHave('compaign.leads.conversions')
            ->whereBetween('created_at', [Carbon::now(), Carbon::now()->addDays($x)])
            ->get();
```

> **Querying Relationship Absence:** When accessing the records for a model, you may wish to limit your results based on the absence of a relationship. For example, imagine you want to retrieve all blog posts that don't have any comments. To do so, you may pass the name of the relationship to the `doesntHave` method

**UPDATE**

As per the updated question conditions, according to my understanding the leads can be obtained by:

```
$leads = Lead::whereHas('compaign', function($q) use($compaign) {
    $q->has('crons')
      ->where('id', $compaign->id);
      // Use the above line if in case of a compaign is to be filtered out
})->doesntHave('conversions')
->whereBetween('created_at', [Carbon::now(), Carbon::now()->addDays($x)])
->get();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: the thing is that the lead might exist in the **conversions** table, it'll simply exist under a different *campaign_id* this is a really tricky one.

Also the solution you give returns **Crons** doesn't it? Not a Collection of Leads.

I need to get the leads, not the crons, i just need to make sure that.


`A - The leads belong to a campaign associated with the Cron via a Many-To-Many relationship.`

`2 - They have no record in the *conversions* table **Under this specific campaign** or if they do, that the lead is **older** than X amount of days.`